# Mac filtering on Django?

Tags: django, networking, mac-address, whitelist

Is there a package or `how to`?, on Django that allows to whitelist a mac address that stored on a model.

```
class mac_address(models.Model):
    mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=17)
```

That only listed mac addresses are only able to access the webapp, since IP whitelisting is kinda complicated because it's changes from time to time.

Comment: MAC filtering is pretty pointless because it is so easy to change a MAC address. Never base security on an address, MAC or IP.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [django-ratelimit](https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and identify the request per the mac_address.